# MS GRAPH API - CREATE SUBSCRIPTIONS - 403 ERROR - Caller does not have access to resource

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

### Background:

Hi, I'm trying to use the ms graph API with ROPC authentication (other auth methods were not working since I need a non-interactive login for delegated permissions) to faciliate sending channel messages back and forth from specific Teams channels and my chat application. This process is working on loading/sending messages but to get real time updates it looks like I need to be able to subscribe to a resource (outgoing webhooks require mentions and this isn't what I want, though I can set it up and it works).

### Issue:

To subscribe to a resource (ms teams channel) I'm using the code below:

```
  const token = VALID_TOKEN_HERE // from ROPC auth flow
  const url = `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions`
  const subscription = {
    changeType: 'created,updated',
    notificationUrl: `${MY_ENDPOINT}/api/teams/events`,
    resource: `teams/${MY_TENANT_ID}/channels/${MY_CHANNEL_ID}/messages`,
    expirationDateTime: moment().add(1, 'hours'),
    includeResourceData: false,
  }
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  }

  const response = await axios.post(url, subscription, config).catch(e => console.log(e) )
```

After posting to this url I get back the verify token req from Teams to my notificationUrl route which is set up like below:

```
    router.post('/teams/events', async (req, res) => {
        if (req.query.validationToken) {
          res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
          return res.status(200).send(req.query.validationToken);
        }

    // code that does things with notification below
```

### Error:

However, the original request to create a subscription fails and I get the following:

**'Operation: Create;Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden;Reason: Caller does not have access to '/teams('TEAM_ID_HERE')/channels('CHANNEL_ID_HERE')/messages' resource]'**

Other info:
It is a standard (not private) channel with my user as a member

I'm requesting these permissions when getting my auth token **'ChannelMessage.Read.All Group.ReadWrite.All Directory.ReadWrite.All ChannelMessage.Send user.read openid profile offline_access'**

[My API permissions look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePQow.png)

What am I missing to be able to create a subscription?

Comment: hello @David, Can you please check if you are able to [list the messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) using the same bearer_token?

Comment: I tested using the accesstoken generated from ROPC flow  using postman and performed list operation and it was successful. you can refer [Image1](https://i.imgur.com/9E2BeUt.png) and [Image2](https://i.imgur.com/Oqjs8kq.png)

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT Yes, I'm able to list the messages using the same endpoint you mentioned using the same bearer_token. I have to do that for another portion of the app. Does this relate to being able to subscribe to a resource?

Comment: As per error you have received `Operation: Create;Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden;Reason: Caller does not have access to '/teams('TEAM_ID_HERE')/channels('CHANNEL_ID_HERE')/messages' resource]` ., I was confirming this as when you subscribe to message resource your app should be able to read the messages .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying to make it work on the microsoft graph explorer I realized that the resource url path I was trying to access had the wrong id.

teams/${**MY_TENANT_ID**}/channels/${MY_CHANNEL_ID}/messages

should have been

teams/${**MY_GROUP_ID**}/channels/${MY_CHANNEL_ID}/messages

This was the source of the error and changing the id fixed it.